# Example for CREATE TABLE on TRINO using HUDI

Tags: apache-spark, create-table, trino, apache-hudi

I am using `Spark Structured Streaming (3.1.1)` to read data from `Kafka` and use `HUDI (0.8.0)` as the storage system on S3 partitioning the data by date. (no problems with this section)

I am looking to use `Trino (355)` to be able to query that data. As a pre-curser, I've already placed the `hudi-presto-bundle-0.8.0.jar` in `/data/trino/hive/`

I created a table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE table_new (
  columns, dt
) WITH (
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['dt'], 
  external_location = 's3a://bucket/location/',
  format = 'parquet'
);
```

Even after calling the below function, trino is unable to discover any partitions

```
CALL system.sync_partition_metadata('schema', 'table_new', 'ALL')
```

My assessment is that I am unable to create a table under trino using hudi largely due to the fact that I am not able to pass the right values under `WITH` Options.
I am also unable to find a create table example under documentation for HUDI.

I would really appreciate if anyone can give me a example for that, or point me to the right direction, if in case I've missed anything.

Really appreciate the help

---

Small Update:
Tried Adding

```
connector = 'hudi'
```

but this throws the error:

```
Catalog 'hive' does not support table property 'connector'
```

Comment: Do you get any output when running sync_partition_metadata? You should verify you are pointing to a catalog either in the session or our url string.

Comment: @BrianOlsen no output at all when i call sync_partition_metadata.
Also when logging into trino-cli i do pass the parameter `--catalog hive`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below?
[image]

Reference: https://hudi.apache.org/docs/next/querying_data/#trino
https://hudi.apache.org/docs/query_engine_setup/#PrestoDB

Comment: yes, i did actaully, the documentation primarily revolves around querying data and not how to create a table, hence looking for an example if possible

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, you can only query HUDI tables with Trino/Presto. Creating tables is not supported, so as inserting/updating data.

Check out the Writing Data document where it mentions Spark and Flink are the only engine with write.
Ref: https://hudi.apache.org/docs/writing_data